Hitting something hard drilling a screw near my curved molding in a 1906 ceiling - looks like sandy stone with hair in it - what is that?
** Updated with what I found in the drilled hole
Can I just drill through it with a masonry bit, or do I need to be careful? It's a 1906 brick row house that was gut renovated in 2015. Nothing shows up on the stud finder.  The hardness only seems to be near the molding, it seems like new regular drywall at the rest of the ceiling, probably done during the renovation. Nothing shows up on the studfinder. It's not metal and looks like sandy stone with hair in it.
This is at the front of the house just under the flat roof part where it slants up.
Spot marked in red

I stuck a microscope in the hole and see what looks like yellow sandy masonry with hair in it - is that old mortar or cement?


Without knowing more about the house, where the receptacles/lights/plumbing is, it is hard to tell what it might be.  Do you have a magnet stud finder/compass?  A question a few days ago, the OP found/drilled right on top of a hidden nail head.

I used a regular studfinder and a walabot scanner - but neither found anything.  I'll post the blueprints as well

I would guess it's metal studs. I've run into this a few times and have screwed a drywall screw up there and whacked it with a hammer. If it's a metal stud, the screw will pierce the stud, conduit or a pipe and the tip of the screw will flatten a bit. This is just my method so not guaranteed to work.

When contemplating the "go for it!" option in unknown construction, contemplate the possibility of gas pipe, water pipe, sewer pipe, and electrical conduit, or protection plates protecting those services...

It could be a lot of things, a nail, an electrical box, metal pipe (old houses did not use plastic pipes), a metal beam, a metal stud,  or maybe even some other memento that someone stuck up there.  One could drill a larger hole and snake a camera up there for a look as that type of hole would be easy to fix.  I would be careful not to cause a larger problem.

So on your plan what about useful things like where water comes in, gas comes in, electricity comes in? Even then there may be gas pipes to old capped service points on walls etc.

I stuck a microscope in and found what looks like sandy stone with hair in it - what could that be?

This is one of those times I gauge my need to have the hole or mount things , with the  possibility of causing a major problem that will take much more work and money to correct.

What do you plan on mounting there?  You may be able to put in a plastic anchor and be done with it.  How much weight needs to be hung?  Do you need 2 holes?  Do you need more?  Can you move where you want something to hang?  More info about what you actually are trying to accomplish would help here.

it's some sheer curtains and a plastic curtain track - I can use a plastic anchor but am nervous about drilling through something dangerous or something like asbestos

Do not just drill through it with any bit.
There are good reasons to not force your way through hard objects hidden in your walls, and there are good workarounds.
In this case: Buy a dual-lens borescope with screen. Spend more than $50 and less than $100. Do not buy one that needs a phone, you'll regret it.
Use a 1/16" drill bit to find a place nearby where you do not hit anything. When you find one, expand that hole to 1/2" and look inside with the camera. Then you will know what you are drilling into.
Patching and painting will be a minor pain, but tiny patches in the ceiling don't draw much attention from the ground and are a lot less painful than a burst pipe.  White patching compound on a 1/16" hole in a white ceiling does not even need to be painted.

Just updated the question with the results of the boroscope - it looks like yellow sandy masonry with hair in it.

Masonry with hair in it sounds like old style horsehair plaster. But while that is harder than plasterboard, I haven't heard of it being hard enough that you couldn't go through it fairly easily. This is almost sounding like construction adhesive that just happened to have hair caught in it...?

I just saw this April 10 comment.    Sorry.  My suggestion was not to look into the hard material with the borescope, although that is certainly useful.  It was to probe for a place nearby where the ceiling is hollow, and examine the vicinity of the hard material from there so you hopefully can determine its shape and function.  Your observation is also useful.  I wonder why "Sandy stone with hair in it" is hard enough to make you stop drilling and ask questions.  That's usually only metal.
